# how to put isActive for More than one page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a side bar menu collapsible submenu in my Angular project. I used isActive comment for showing active state. When i refresh any page it should show the particular menu with active state. it works on when i refresh submenu's first link. If i click submenu's second link, it doesn't work.

I dont know how to declare active more than a link. `ng-class="{show:isActive('/create-workorder')}"`

My code is below

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="flevel ">Work </a>
        <ul class="second_level" ng-class="{show:isActive('/create-workorder')}">
            <li>
                <a href="#/create-workorder" class="" ng-class="{active_sub:isActive('/create-workorder')}">
                    <div class="create_wo"></div>Create WO</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#/workorder-all" class="" ng-class="{active_sub:isActive('/workorder-all')}">
                    <div class="overall_queue"></div>Overall all</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="flevel ">Status </a>
        <ul class="second_level" ng-class="{show:isActive('/history')}">
            <li>
                <a href="#/history" class="" ng-class="{active_sub:isActive('/history')}">
                    <div class="status"></div>History</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#/recent" class="" ng-class="{active_sub:isActive('/recent')}">
                    <div class="recent"></div>Recent</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common technique to use to determine active menu is to use the URL itself.
On page refresh you can check the URL and highlight corresponding menu.

For parent-child menu, you can choose to code the relationship, e.g. specify that you should also highlight "status" when you highlight "history".
Or you can use URL itself for the structure, e.g. `#/status/history` instead of `#/history`.

Comment: Yes this will work. But my sidebar menu has Submeu with Show/Hide type. Lets say, i m in the first submenu page and i refresh the page & it works with active state with submenu visible state. If your in the second submenut, refresh page, entire submenus hided state... What should i do here.

Comment: ng-class="{show:isActive('/create-workorder')}" This is the comment for showing submenu list. Here i added veryfirst submenu... How to declare another submenu

Comment: you can put `ng-class="{show:isActive('/history') || isActive('/recent')}"` if you don't want to use parent-child relationship